# solving an integral equation2

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can one solve the following equation?
$$\dfrac{xye^{\int (4xf+2yx^{3})dx}}{\int xye^{\int (4xf+2yx^{3})dx}dx} = 2$$
where $f$ and $y$ are the real function of $x$.

I would like to get $y$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want y' in terms of x,y,f or y in terms of x,y',f? Or none of the above :P

Comment: none of them. I want y in terms of $x,f$.